# Sliding pages + wordpress

Tags: javascript, navigation, content

do you have any idea how to achieve such effect with wordpress?
http://www.papajastudio.pl/
http://soulwire.co.uk/

I mean the navigation. i want to have simple cms to edit website content + such sliding effect. An ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is what came to mind though there could be some easy implementations as well:

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){`

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
    if(jQuery(document).scrollTop()>0){
        jQuery('#first-header').hide();
        jQuery('#second-header').show();
    }
    else{
        jQuery('#second-header').hide();
        jQuery('#first-header').show();
    }
})
```

})

Comment: You can also add animate effect of jquery in conjunction with the hide and show or may be slow down the show and hide statements with timeouts so as to get the desired effects

Answer (score 0):

***Note - Sliding effects has nothing to do with Wordpress.*** (or any CMS)

Wordpress is a server side structure, uses `php` and `MySQL database` to generate content for site *( Like other CSM does )*, Uses the [themes](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/) to show them. You have to use `JavaScript` and `CSS` to achieve those visual *( sliding )* effects.

Or you can head to [Wordpress plugin Directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/), and search for a plugin to do this for you.

> #### Note -
>
> Those sliders, you are referring to needs some `basic html structure`, that can be achieved by customizing your theme.

Comment: Its better to answer this in a comment, because it will very likely be closed.